# How To Get Particular Values From Json Response Using Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing

I am trying to get `response` of `first key` value without mentioning key name of `"A"` using `objective C`. I cant get exactly, please help me to get from below response.

```
NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves | NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

NSDictionary *response = [JSON[@"response"]firstObject];


response = {
    A =     {
        company =         (
                        {
                no = "115";
                student = "Mich";
                school =                 (
                                        {
                        grade = A;

                    }
                );
                test = "<null>";
                office = tx;
            }
      );
   };
}
```

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered, so a message of `firstObject` doesn't make sense.  If you want to impose ordering, you'll need to sort `[JSON allKeys]`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this, depending on your exact requirements.  If you just need to access the value of each key in `JSON[@"response"]`, you can enumerate the `JSON` dictionary:

```
[JSON enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary *)obj;

    ...

    if (shouldStop) { // whatever condition you want, if any
        *stop = YES;
    }
}];
```

If you want some kind of ordering, you need to use `[JSON allKeys]`:

```
NSArray *keys = [[JSON allKeys] sortedArrayUsing...];  // Use whichever sort method you like
for (NSString *key in keys) {
    NSDictionary *dict = JSON[key];

    ...
}
```

If all you want are the values, you can use `[JSON allValues]`.  Sort if desired.